# Invoke selector after user allows Location tracking for app

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager

When an app requests for `CLLocationManager` location for the first time, an `alertView` pops up asking the user to allow/deny location tracking. How do I invoke a selector when the user selects OK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `CLLocationManager` delegate method `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` to be notified when the user has changed the status.

Comment: This is weird. The method is called repeatedly, and doesn't stop.

Comment: What is the stack trace each time it's called?

Comment: I just placed an `NSLog` in it, and as soon as `startUpdatingLocation` the `locationManager`, the method keeps getting called over and over again. The application does not crash.

Comment: Turns out, I was re-initializing my `locationManager` in the method I was calling from `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:`